# Converter número numa string para duas casa decimais

Tags: c#, string, conversão

Imaginemos uma string com o seguinte valor: 12,126456

Como faço para converter a string para 12,12?

Preciso de converter, usando C#, de maneira a que a string final tenha no máximo dois dígitos depois da vírgula.

tentei o `String.Format("{0:#,00}", valor )` mas não resultou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já que não necessita de arredondar, basta usar a simples manipulação da *string*:

```
var valor = "12,126456";
var commaPosition = valor.IndexOf(",", StringComparison.Ordinal);
var result = commaPosition+3 > valor.Length ? valor: valor.Substring(0, commaPosition + 3);
```

Veja no [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LhXYM7)

Comment: esse foi o método que eu achei mais eficiente, e mais simples ;)

Comment: sim é simples, mas lembre de testar se a string contém a "," antes de manipula-la, faça um teste com "12" por exemplo. @ihavenokia

Comment: Sim, e também se a string não tem menos de 2 dígitos depois da vírgula

Comment: @RovannLinhalis A resposta aponta para uma possível abordagem, não era intenção dar um código pronto para produção. Entretanto alterei para lidar com a situação de nº de casas decimais inferior a duas.

Comment: sim, foi apenas uma observação pra ele tomar na implementação. =]

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Sim, e agradeço o comentário, pois permitiu-me corrigi-lo.

Answer (score 2):

Basta Converter para decimal, e depois usar o ToString especificando o formato.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string numero = "12,126456";
        decimal d;
        if (decimal.TryParse(numero,NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"), out d))
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Arredondado: " + d.ToString("N2"));

           decimal t = Math.Truncate(d*100)/100;
           Console.WriteLine("Truncado: "+ t.ToString("0.##")); 

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Número inválido");
        }

    }
}
```

> Resultado:
>
> **Arredondado: 12.13**
>
> **Truncado: 12.12**

Coloquei no .NETFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7ErUSv

Comment: Só para complementar, se deseja que dê 12.12 tem que truncar o valor antes, já que a formatação usará arredondamento padrão.

Comment: Adicionei a parte de truncar =] obrigado @Maniero

Comment: não funciona com negativos esse método

Comment: @ihavenokia Resolvido a questão dos negativos

Answer (score 1):

```
Decimal meuValor = 0;
String minhaString = "010,87147";

meuValor = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(minhaString), 2);
```

Não tratei erros, sua string deve sempre conter uma virgula para funcionar corretamente. 
Se estiver utilizando "CultureInfo("en-US") dê um replace na virgula pra ser ponto. ex:

```
minhaString.Replace(",", ".")
```

Faça isso antes de atribuir o valor a variável Decimal.