# Preciso saber quando o usuário usa ponto ou vírgula em números decimais

Tags: c#, .net, formatação

Estou desenvolvendo um exercício cujo resultado é diferente em cenários que o usuário usa ponto ou virgula para colocar seu número decimal, no caso coloquei como variável do tipo `double`

```
Console.WriteLine("Caculadora de Imc\n\n\n");
Console.WriteLine("Digite o seu peso atual \n");
int peso = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Digite agora a sua altura \n");
double altura = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
double imc = peso / (altura * altura);
Console.WriteLine("Seu imc corresponde a {0}", imc);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Como faço pra saber quando o usuário digita virgula ou ponto no decimal?

Comment: Você quer ignorar o que o usuário digitar, e sempre calcular como vírgula?

Comment: na verdade quero identificar que ele usou ponto e avisa-lo para utilizar virgula, mais sempre calcular com virgula, independentemente se ele usar ponto parece uma boa

Comment: Em interface gráfica dá pra tratar melhor isso, mas o correto é deixar que o usuário passe com ponto e/ou vírgula, tudo bem que no seu escopo só entraria o ponto se o peso da pessoa fosse informado em gramas (outro problema que você não especifica a unidade que o usuário precisa informar) mas não é o caso. Sugiro que faça como Maniero falou, usando o TryParse, Há poucos dias respondi uma questão sobre conversão que você pode ver aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/251920/69359 . Espero que ajude =]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você tem que usar o método que permite indicar formatos. Veja o [`TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Decimal_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Decimal__).

Qualquer outra solução é gambiarra. Mesmo esta precisa ser bem pensada. Imagina se o usuário digitar tanto o ponto, quanto a virgula. E se ele colocar outras coisas? Você pode usar a [cultura](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0) que mais se adequada ao que precisa.

Se isto não for suficiente, e é bem melhor que verificar se tem um monto ou uma vírgula, aí terá que criar um algoritmo que verifique completamente como está escrito e dizer com detalhes o que está errado, o que dará muito trabalho. Precisa ver se compensa. A forma que eu apresentei não é perfeita, mas não aceita dado formatado errado. Qualquer forma que aceite dado errado não pode ser usada. Obviamente que se a pessoa entra um número errado em formato certo não tem o que fazer.

Toda conversão de dados entrados por um usuário deve ser verificada se foi bem-sucedida. Nestes casos você nunca pode usar o `Parse()` puro porque se a digitação for errada vai quebrar a aplicação. Este método só pode ser usado quando há certeza do formato do dado a ser convertido. Este é um erro comum que a maioria dos programadores cometem.

Se está convertendo para `decimal`, e geralmente é o mais adequado, guarde um uma variável `decimal` e não `double`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Para verificar se ele está usando ponto ou virgula, você pode usar o `Contains()`:

```
string alturaIn = Console.ReadLine();
if (alturaIn.Contains(".")){
    Console.WriteLine("Contem ponto.");
}
else if (alturaIn.Contains(",")){
    Console.WriteLine("Contem virgula.");
}
double altura = double.Parse(alturaIn);
double imc = peso / (altura * altura);
```

Se você quer trocar de virgula para ponto e vice-versa, você pode utilizar o `Replace()`:

```
if (alturaIn.Contains(".")){
    alturaIn.Replace(".", ","); //Troca por virgula
}
else if (alturaIn.Contains(",")){
    alturaIn.Replace(",", "."); //Troca por ponto
}
```