# Variavel double recebendo valor com vírgula na API - .NetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

Olá,

Criei uma API que recebe dois parametros de outro projeto(requisito do trabalho da faculdade), é o cálculo do IMC, então ele recebe peso e altura e faz o cálculo, até aí tranquilo.

---- API

```
namespace API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class IMCController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(double peso, double altura)
        {
            string stg = "";
            //os parametros devem ser passados pela url.
            // EX:  api/ExercicioAPI?peso=75&altura=1.69


            if (peso != 0 && altura != 0)
            {
                double valor = peso / (altura * altura);
                stg = valor.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                stg = "0";
            }

            string json = "{ imc: " + double.Parse(stg).ToString("0.00") + "}";

            return json;
        }
    }
}
```

---- Na controller do projeto, recebo assim:

```
public double getImc(double peso, double altura)
    {

        double imc = 0;
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            //double teste = 1.59;
            string url = "http://localhost:61822/api/IMC?peso=" + 59 + "&altura=" + altura;
            string json = client.DownloadString(url);

            imc = Convert.ToDouble(new string(json.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));

        }
        return imc;
    }
```

---

Todas as vezes a string url recebe o valor com vírgula ex. 1,59, mesmo vindo como string, int, double.

Mesmo quando testei com a variável "teste" ali, ele passou na variavel url 1,59

[image: teste]

Tentei passar como string a altura na API e na controller do projeto e antes do cálculo converter pra double, mas também recebeu com vírgula, ao invés de ponto.

Alguma ideia que problema é esse ou como resolver?
Procurei e não achei nada, tô usando o visual studio em inglês, fiquei pensando que poderia ser algo do sistema do Brasil usar a vírgula em casa decimal e estar convertendo no navegador, mas não achei como corrigir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa definir na API qual será o padrão aceito, particularmente, utilizaria um inteiro representando centímetros, e depois dividiria por 100 para o cálculo.

Quando você faz [double].ToString() ele utiliza a cultura padrão do sistema operacional para a representação, ou seja, se o windows for pt-BR, o resultado será 1,59 e se for en-US será 1.59.

Você pode especificar qual cultura utilizar para a string, inclusive uma invariante. Exemplos:

```
    altura.ToString("N2"); //Utiliza o padrão do SO
    altura.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ); //invariante 1.59
    altura.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR")); // 1,59
    altura.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")); //1.59
```

No seu controller, caso defina que o padrão será pt-BR, ou seja, vírgula terá que fazer o parse especificando isso:

```
    string s = "1,59";
    double d;
    if (double.TryParse(s,NumberStyles.Float,CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"), out d))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("valor: "+d);    
    }
```

Documentação
[ToString](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=netframework-4.8)
[TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)
[CultureInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=netframework-4.8)

Código de exemplo no [.netFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/feEl8N) (o padrão do .netfiddle é en-US ;) )

> Quando for fazer o Parse de algum valor, utilize o TryParse, aqui tem uma resposta do maniero para uma questão semelhante a sua: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252560/69359 e na comunidade há várias outras respostas demonstrando a utilização.
>
> Não entrei na questão do json se não iria fugir da pergunta e talvez ainda não viu sobre em aula, mas poderia ser uma classe serializada apenas, e não escrever o json "na mão"